# Does the BXR-55 BATTLER's intrinsic perk work with Rangefinder?

Tags: destiny-2

I had a [BXR-Battler](https://www.light.gg/db/items/2708806099/bxr-55-battler/) rifle drop for me and it has the [Rangefinder](https://www.light.gg/db/items/2846385770/rangefinder/) perk on it. Initially it seemed like a reasonable roll.

[image: BXR-55 Battler with Rangefinder perk]

However the frame perk is all about hip-fire.

> Customized frame with dramatically increased accuracy, stability and targeting while hip firing.

Where as Rangefinder is all about 'aiming', which I assume is aiming down sights.

> Aiming this weapon increases its effective range and zoom magnification.

Do these two perks work in opposition? So when I ADS (aim down sights) with it, I will lose it's frame perk and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posed this question to the folks over on the [LowSodiumDestiny sub-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LowSodiumDestiny/comments/semsd3/does_the_bxr55_battlers_intrinsic_perk_work_with/?sort=new) and they have confirmed my suspicions.

> Yes when you ADS is when rangefinder will work but not the intrinsic
> perk. When you hip fire the intrinsic perk will work but not
> rangefinder.
>
> It doesn’t work against each other as having rangefinder
> on this weapon will be beneficial for when you ads. So you will have
> great hip fire because of the intrinsic perk and solid range when you
> ads.